# Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 : Broken Update

Tags: apt, ubuntu-20.04, dpkg

I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 using :

```
do-release-upgrade
```

After downloading all the packages it asked me if I wanted to keep my version of an existing config file. Trying to exit out of the file, I used Ctrl + C, which caused the entire update process to abort.

On rebooting, I googled and found that the way to proceed was with:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

However I believe a large number of packages are completely broken.
I have tried virtually everything I can find including:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I have attempted to manually install some of the packages, but each time it complains about some other package that depends on some other package, that depends on another package.

The over-arching problem is that the "apt-get" command simply cannot go forward, as each time, it responds with the around 100 unmet dependencies.

Any help is appreciated. Short of a complete format and re-installation of Ubuntu,I have no idea what to do.

Here is my output from using "dpkg --configure -a":

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip:
 hplip depends on hplip-data (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2); however:
  Version of hplip-data on system is 3.17.10+repack0-5.
 hplip depends on libhpmud0 (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2); however:
  Version of libhpmud0:amd64 on system is 3.17.10+repack0-5.
 hplip depends on printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2); however:
  Version of printer-driver-hpcups on system is 3.17.10+repack0-5.

dpkg: error processing package hplip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on librhythmbox-core10 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2); however:
  Version of librhythmbox-core10:amd64 on system is 3.4.2-4ubuntu1.
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on rhythmbox (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2); however:
  Version of rhythmbox on system is 3.4.2-4ubuntu1.
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2); however:
  Version of gir1.2-rb-3.0:amd64 on system is 3.4.2-4ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapt-pkg-perl:
 libapt-pkg-perl depends on perl-base (>= 5.30.0-9build1); however:
  Version of perl-base on system is 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5.
 libapt-pkg-perl depends on perlapi-5.30.0; however:
  Package perlapi-5.30.0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libapt-pkg-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tables-lib:
 python3-tables-lib depends on libhdf5-103; however:
  Package libhdf5-103 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python3-tables-lib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64:
 libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 depends on libicu-le-hb0 (= 1.0.3+git180724-3build2); however:
  Version of libicu-le-hb0:amd64 on system is 1.0.3+git161113-4.

dpkg: error processing package libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 depends on gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.40.0); however:
  Version of gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 on system is 2.36.11-2.
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 depends on gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.41.0); however:
  Version of gir1.2-pango-1.0:amd64 on system is 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1.
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.7); however:
  Version of libgtk-3-0:amd64 on system is 3.22.30-1ubuntu4.

dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglib-object-introspection-perl:
 libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 (1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1) breaks libglib-object-introspection-perl (<< 0.048-2~) and is installed.
  Version of libglib-object-introspection-perl to be configured is 0.044-2.

dpkg: error processing package libglib-object-introspection-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-brlapi:amd64:
 python3-brlapi:amd64 depends on libbrlapi0.7; however:
  Package libbrlapi0.7 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python3-brlapi:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gimp:
 gimp depends on libgimp2.0 (>= 2.10.18); however:
  Version of libgimp2.0 on system is 2.8.22-1.
 gimp depends on gimp-data (>= 2.10.18); however:
  Version of gimp-data on system is 2.8.22-1.
 gimp depends on libgegl-0.4-0 (>= 0.4.22); however:
  Package libgegl-0.4-0 is not installed.
 gimp depends on libheif1 (>= 1.4.0); however:
  Package libheif1 is not installed.
 gimp depends on libilmbase24 (>= 2.3.0); however:
  Package libilmbase24 is not installed.
 gimp depends on libmypaint-1.5-1 (>= 1.5.0); however:
  Package libmypaint-1.5-1 is not installed.
 gimp depends on libopenexr24 (>= 2.3.0); however:
  Package libopenexr24 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gimp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnupg:
 gnupg depends on gpgv (>= 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1); however:
  Version of gpgv on system is 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.4.

dpkg: error processing package gnupg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gpg-agent:
 gpg-agent depends on init-system-helpers (>= 1.52); however:
  Version of init-system-helpers on system is 1.51.

dpkg: error processing package gpg-agent (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libhdf5-cpp-103:amd64:
 libhdf5-cpp-103:amd64 depends on libhdf5-103; however:
  Package libhdf5-103 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libhdf5-cpp-103:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on libpython3-dev (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2); however:
  Version of libpython3-dev:amd64 on system is 3.6.7-1~18.04.
 python3-dev depends on python3.8-dev (>= 3.8.2-1~); however:
  Package python3.8-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libhdf5-dev:
 libhdf5-dev depends on libhdf5-103 (= 1.10.4+repack-11ubuntu1); however:
  Package libhdf5-103 is not installed.
 libhdf5-dev depends on libhdf5-cpp-103 (= 1.10.4+repack-11ubuntu1); however:
  Package libhdf5-cpp-103:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libhdf5-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aptitude:
 aptitude depends on aptitude-common (= 0.8.12-1ubuntu4); however:
  Package aptitude-common is not installed.
 aptitude depends on libboost-iostreams1.71.0; however:
  Package libboost-iostreams1.71.0 is not installed.
 aptitude depends on libcwidget4 (>= 0.5.18-1); however:
  Package libcwidget4 is not installed.
 aptitude depends on libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0); however:
  Package libsigc++-2.0-0v5 is not installed.
 aptitude depends on libxapian30 (>= 1.4.14~); however:
  Version of libxapian30:amd64 on system is 1.4.5-1ubuntu0.1.

dpkg: error processing package aptitude (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gpg-wks-server:
 gpg-wks-server depends on gpg-agent (= 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package gpg-agent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gpg-wks-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tables:
 python3-tables depends on python3-tables-lib (>= 3.6.1-2build1); however:
  Package python3-tables-lib is not configured yet.
 python3-tables depends on python3-tables-lib (<< 3.6.1-2build1.1~); however:
  Package python3-tables-lib is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-tables (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gpg-wks-client:
 gpg-wks-client depends on gpg-agent (= 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package gpg-agent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gpg-wks-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgjs0g:
 libgjs0g depends on gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (>= 3.20); however:
  Package gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 (1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1) breaks libgjs0g (<< 1.58.1-2~) and is installed.
  Version of libgjs0g to be configured is 1.52.5-0ubuntu18.04.1.

dpkg: error processing package libgjs0g (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gi:
 libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 (1.64.1-1~ubuntu20.04.1) breaks python-gi (<< 3.34.0-4~) and is installed.
  Version of python-gi to be configured is 3.26.1-2ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package python-gi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-protobuf:
 python3-protobuf depends on libprotobuf17; however:
  Package libprotobuf17 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python3-protobuf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-uno:
 python3-uno depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) | libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1); however:
  Version of libreoffice-core on system is 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10.
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.
 python3-uno depends on libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha); however:
  Package libuno-cppu3 is not installed.
 python3-uno depends on libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha); however:
  Package libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 is not installed.
 python3-uno depends on libuno-sal3 (>= 5.4.0~alpha); however:
  Package libuno-sal3 is not installed.
 python3-uno depends on libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta); however:
  Package libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 is not installed.
 python3-uno depends on uno-libs-private; however:
  Package uno-libs-private is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-mpi-python-dev:
 libboost-mpi-python-dev depends on libboost-mpi-python1.71-dev; however:
  Package libboost-mpi-python1.71-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libboost-mpi-python-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwayland-dev:amd64:
 libwayland-dev:amd64 depends on libwayland-client0 (= 1.18.0-1); however:
  Version of libwayland-client0:amd64 on system is 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.3.
 libwayland-dev:amd64 depends on libwayland-egl1 (= 1.18.0-1); however:
  Version of libwayland-egl1:amd64 on system is 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.3.
 libwayland-dev:amd64 depends on libwayland-bin (= 1.18.0-1); however:
  Version of libwayland-bin on system is 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.3.

dpkg: error processing package libwayland-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dirmngr:
 dirmngr depends on init-system-helpers (>= 1.52); however:
  Version of init-system-helpers on system is 1.51.

dpkg: error processing package dirmngr (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libyaml-libyaml-perl:
 libyaml-libyaml-perl depends on perl (>= 5.30.0-9); however:
  Version of perl on system is 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5.
 libyaml-libyaml-perl depends on perlapi-5.30.0; however:
  Package perlapi-5.30.0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libyaml-libyaml-perl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libharfbuzz-dev:amd64:
 libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 depends on libharfbuzz0b (= 2.6.4-1ubuntu4); however:
  Version of libharfbuzz0b:amd64 on system is 1.7.2-1ubuntu1.
 libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 depends on libharfbuzz-gobject0 (= 2.6.4-1ubuntu4); however:
  Version of libharfbuzz-gobject0:amd64 on system is 1.7.2-1ubuntu1.
 libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 depends on gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 (= 2.6.4-1ubuntu4); however:
  Version of gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0:amd64 on system is 1.7.2-1ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libharfbuzz-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsane-hpaio:amd64:
 libsane-hpaio:amd64 depends on libhpmud0 (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0); however:
  Version of libhpmud0:amd64 on system is 3.17.10+repack0-5.

dpkg: error processing package libsane-hpaio:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-h5py:
 python3-h5py depends on libhdf5-openmpi-103 (>= 1.10.3); however:
  Package libhdf5-openmpi-103 is not installed.
 python3-h5py depends on python3-mpi4py; however:
  Package python3-mpi4py is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python3-h5py (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hplip
 rhythmbox-plugins
 libapt-pkg-perl
 python3-tables-lib
 libicu-le-hb-dev:amd64
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64
 libglib-object-introspection-perl
 python3-brlapi:amd64
 gimp
 gnupg
 gpg-agent
 libhdf5-cpp-103:amd64
 python3-dev
 libhdf5-dev
 aptitude
 gpg-wks-server
 python3-tables
 gpg-wks-client
 libgjs0g
 python-gi
 python3-protobuf
 python3-uno
 libboost-mpi-python-dev
 libwayland-dev:amd64
 dirmngr
 libyaml-libyaml-perl
 libharfbuzz-dev:amd64
 libsane-hpaio:amd64
 python3-h5py
```

Comment: This question does not appear to be on topic. Home and end user computing questions can be asked on [su], and questions specifically about Ubuntu can be asked on [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently repaired a failed "do-release-upgrade" between these same Ubuntu versions on a web server. It was a lot of work (paid, fortunately!). Too much to list here, but basically it involved uninstalling and reinstalling failing packages, removing and re-adding user accounts and so on. No "magic bullet" command. In your case it looks like you're running apps like LibreOffice which would be even more work.

The good news is I eventually succeeded, but I wouldn't really recommend it if there's a backup of user data available. It would usually be easier to back up user files, reinstall the OS and then restore the apps and user files.

I've also attempted to run "do-release-upgrade" on a virtual machine as an experiment to see if I could upgrade my own webserver (which uses Virtualmin as a control panel) this way. It worked fine if I loaded a factory version of Ubuntu 18.04 and ran do-release-upgrade to get it to 20.04 before loading Virtualmin and then restoring websites. The other way round it was a mess.

So, probably not the answer you were looking for but perhaps it will save you some heartache.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the below command and it worked for me.

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: But note that OP did write `sudo apt-get install -f` where `-f` means `--fix-broken`: OP already tried this and still had to ask a question. Your answer adds nothing. (ok except for the case where `apt`'s additional function over `apt-get`: remove packages in the way, would have helped).